# Rails 5.2 each statement without duplicates values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, each

```
<% Schedule.all.each do |schedule| %>
  <%= link_to schedule.county, events_path(County: schedule.county) %>
```

Displays duplicates in the Schedule table

I've tried all below without luck in displaying no duplicates.

```
<% Schedule.all.each.uniq do |schedule| %>

<% Schedule.distinct.pluck(:county) do |schedule| %>

<% Schedule.distinct.each.pluck(:county) do |schedule| %>
```

They display nothing for some reason.

Edit:

Associations --

Event has_many :schedules, inverse_of: :event
Schedule belongs_to :event

So the original each block does bring in what I want but grabs the county for each schedule in the database. This results in duplicate county listings. I'm trying to remove these duplicates which I presumed was simple enough by adding a uniq method to the statement but looks like it requires joins. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If a `county` can (and is) associated with more than one `schedule`, then, naturally, you will have duplicate `counties` displayed. Your approach, BTW, is going to give you a N+1 query. Time to use `joins`.

Comment: More joins? Lovely. Well the above I thought would bring in all counties based on each schedule created. I'd end up with a list of say 20, some being of the same county. 

I guessed there was an easy way to just call unique on that results by combining .uniq or .distinct with the loop.

Probably thinking about it ***ways. I'll rethink it and venture back into Join territory. Thanks @jvillian.

Comment: If you want to post models and relations, maybe somebody will add some clue..

Comment: I thought it was just an easy fix being able to remove duplicates and I was doing something wrong. wasn't sure it was relating to joins and the way my models where set up. Will look into it a bit more and revert if I cant solve it. Thanks @iGian

Comment: You can use a simple `County.includes(:schedules).references(:schedules).where.not(schedules: { id: nil })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% Schedule.select(:county).distinct.each do |schedule| %>
```

So looks like I didn't need a join. It was more just a select and then use distinct method which works. Thanks @Tacyons for putting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the association between schedule and country model. Assuming Schedule belongs to country

```
<% Schedule.joins(country).select(:country).distinct.each do |schedule| %>
  <%= link_to schedule.county, events_path(County: schedule.county) %>
<% end %>
```